# How to get the content of an input stream in reverse order?

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I am using a txt file for my level desing. I use the below to take the contents and convert to string buffer, then iterate through the lines to generate my game objects.

The the problem is that it reads from top down and so I have to design my levels upside down for them to be right way around.

How can I change the stream to read the opposite way? Or write the lines to the String Builder the opposite way?

```
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("LOG", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("LOG", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

Comment: will the `insert()` method of string builder not suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use `sb.insert(0, line + "\n")` instead of `sb.append(line + "\n");`.

This will always add new lines to the front of the string, not append it to the end. Should do exactly what you want and will be just as fast, because StringBuilder is made exactly for things like that.

Comment: Genius. Thanks for that. Sorry to be an idiot, but would you mind briefing explaining why that works?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Till Helge would that be faster/better than appending to sb then returning sb.reverse().toString()

Comment: @artfullyContrived No, but it would be correct in comparison. Only the order of the lines is meant to be reversed, not the entire string.