# How to reverse a InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream, reverse

Suppose i have a input stream and  want to reverse it !

I similar question [How to get the content of an input stream in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16709003/14911094) but firstly thats about 8 years old and also its not what i want exactly!

Suppose i have a InputStream like :

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("some_random_file.bin"));
```

Note this is not specifically for Text files but for binaries!

Now,

I have a way of reversing it :

```
public static InputStream reverseStream(InputStream in) throws Exception{
    byte bytes[] = in.readAllBytes();
    byte bytesRev[] = new byte[bytes.length];
    for(int i=bytes.length - 1, j = 0;i >= 0; i--, j++)
        bytesRev[i] = bytes[j];
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesRev);
}
```

But i am not sure this is the most efficient way to do it!

I want to have a efficient way to achieve this even for Large Files!

Comment: Streams, like their bigger cousins rivers, flow only in one direction. Only with a big enough bucket can you reverse them (once they've fully flown).

Comment: @Kayaman i dont know what size bucket to keep! A huge bucket is not good for a cup water whereas a small one wont work for larger scales! I am looking for a efficient bucket for both tasks together

Comment: You can't *truly* reverse streams is the point I was trying to make. So you can't read a large file in reverse, although you could create a (clumsy) `ReverseFileInputStream`, but that would be silly. Files are meant to be read in one direction, beginning to end (although you can [seek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) inside a file, but that's no longer streaming).

Comment: An example of a stream, is a [livestream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestreaming). You can't reverse that, because the end simply didn't happen yet.

Comment: *Universally and usefully* reversing *any given `InputStream`* is effectively impossible (as Kayaman so poetically proved). But a *specific* solution to reversing the flow of a specific stream is quite possible in some cases. So could you tell us what the underlying goal is? This might just be a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Large earthquakes can reverse a river. Maybe flipping the HDD over violently could reverse the stream.

Comment: @Kayaman - Why is reading a file in reverse "silly"?

Comment: @TedHopp if we consider from the POV of spinning disks, if you're constantly trying to *stream* a file in reverse, maybe it was written the wrong way around. SSDs of course alleviate that problem and there are plenty of `ReverseFileInputStream` implementations available. But you'd need to get something out of it as well, streaming a raw audio file backwards might be semi-useful, but for a general file format? Just use `RandomAccessFile` directly. Reading a file backwards isn't silly (large log files for example), streaming a file backwards is a bit.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011345/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-reverse-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to read the entire file into memory, then your solution is pretty good. The memory footprint can be improved by reversing the contents in placed rather than allocating a second array to store the reversed contents:

```
public static InputStream reverseStream(InputStream in) throws Exception{
    byte bytes[] = in.readAllBytes();
    for(int i=bytes.length - 1, j = 0;i >j; i--, j++) {
        byte tmp = bytes[i];
        bytes[i] = bytes[j];
        bytes[j] = tmp;
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
}
```

If the file is so large that you don't want to load it all at once, then you will need to use class [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to read the file in reverse order. You will need to use some sort of internal buffering to avoid horrible performance. You can wrap this up in your own implementation of `InputStream` that reads backwards through the buffer, loading a new buffer-full on the fly as necessary.

Here's my stab at a class that does this. This code is completely untested (although it compiles).

```
/**
 * An input stream that reads a file in reverse. (UNTESTED)
 *
 * @author Ted Hopp
 */
class ReverseFileInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final RandomAccessFile file;
    /** Internal buffer for reading chunks of the file in reverse. */
    private final byte[] buffer;
    /** Position of the start of the buffer in the file. */
    private long bufferPosition;
    /** Position of the next byte to be read from the buffer. */
    private int bufferCursor;

    public ReverseFileInputStream(File file, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        this.file = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bufferPosition = this.file.length();
        bufferCursor = -1;
    }

    @Override public int read() throws IOException {
        if (bufferCursor < 0) {
            fillBuffer();
        }
        return bufferCursor < 0 ? -1 : (buffer[bufferCursor--] & 0xff);
    }

    @Override public void close() throws IOException {
        file.close();
    }

    private void fillBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (bufferPosition > 0) {
            long newBufferPosition = Math.max(0L, bufferPosition - buffer.length);
            bufferCursor = (int) (bufferPosition - newBufferPosition);
            file.seek(newBufferPosition);
            file.readFully(buffer, 0, bufferCursor--);
            bufferPosition = newBufferPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you try to wrap a `Reader` around this, the result will likely be nonsense unless the text encoding of the underlying file is one byte per character. Likewise with `DataInputStream`, etc.